# How to get path to root folder in for Sphinx template?

Tags: templates, themes, python-sphinx

Some static files from a sphinx template package appear under `/some/path/_static` when my root doc is at `/some/path/index.html`. In my template I want to reference files in the `_static` folder.

Currently I use `src="{{ pathto(master_doc)[:-10] }}_static/...` which looks hacky and only work as long as the root file has a name of the correct length.

Alternatively, I tried `src="{{ pathto(master_doc)}}/../_static/`. This breaks for index.html itself.

Is there a way to get the path of the folder the `master_doc` is in?

Comment: Assuming that one type of static file you have is an image, why not use [`image`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#images)?

Comment: @StevePiercy Thanks! While I can't use `image` in the jinja template, your response triggered me to investigate the `pathto` - actually, having `src="{{ pathto('_static/...', 1) }}` gives me the path I need. Not sure why I missed that before.

Would you like to write an Answer I can accept?

Comment: I've added an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reference a file in Sphinx's static directory from a template, use [`pathto(file, 1)`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/development/templating.html#pathto).

This returns the path to a file which is a filename relative to the root of the generated output. Use this to refer to static files.

For an image, you would use this in the template.

```
src="{{ pathto('_static/my-file.jpg', 1) }}
```